# How to stop the execution of if statement at one time, when condtiion check?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have the custom directive for form validation in angularjs, In this the if condition works fine, but the condition executes multiple times, how to stop the if condition for email and number, when its check one time only. can anyone help me out of this?

Here is my Validate directive.js,

```
app.directive("formValidate", function() {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    template: '<p>Please Fill this Field</p>',
    //scope: true,
    link: function(scope, elem, attr) {

        scope.$watch(attr['ngModel'], function(value) {

                var NameValidator = angular.element("<p class='NameError'>This field is required!</p>");
                var EmailValidator = angular.element("<p class='EmailError'>This Email is Invalid!</p>");
                var PhoneValidator = angular.element("<p class='PhoneError'>Enter Number Only</p>");

                if (attr['name'] == "name") {
                    if (((value || '').toString()).length == 0) {

                        NameValidator.insertAfter(elem);
                        return;


                    } else {
                        var nameRemove = elem[0].nextSibling;
                        nameRemove.remove();

                    }
                }


                if (attr['name'] == 'email') {


                    if (!(/^[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$/.test(value))) {
                        console.log('1:', value);
                        EmailValidator.insertAfter(elem);
                        return;

                    } else {
                        console.log('2:', value);

                        var emailRemove = elem[0].nextSibling;
                        emailRemove.remove();

                    }
                }
                if (attr['name'] == 'number') {
                    if (!(/^[(]{0,1}[0-9]{3}[)]{0,1}[-\s\.]{0,1}[0-9]{3}[-\s\.]{0,1}[0-9]{4}$/.test(value))) {
                        PhoneValidator.insertAfter(elem);
                        return;

                    } else {
                        var phoneRemove = elem[0].nextSibling;
                        phoneRemove.remove();

                    }
                }
            })

    }
}
 });
```

Comment: This looks to be an XY problem. Is the situation here that mutiple validation messages are displayed?

Comment: No, I want to add email error at one time if the condition matches, I don't want it  executes while am typing each letter

Comment: else {

                            var emailRemove = elem[0].nextSibling;
                            emailRemove.remove();
                            return false;

                        }, like this?

Answer (score 0):

U can use return false; for stop execution

```
return false;
```

Comment: At where I want to use this?

Comment: U can apply this in the else part for if the validation of email and number is not done then in else part u can return false to stop execution.

Comment: else { var emailRemove = elem[0].nextSibling; emailRemove.remove(); return false; }, like this?

Comment: Yes u can use or u can also use below return statements to stop execution
return undefined;
return false;
return true;
return "some string";
return 12345;

Comment: will u please see my answer below, it working fine, but the error element hides, it does not remove

Answer (score 0):

Extract the watch function into a function declaration and use the name instead e.g. `scope.$watch(attr['ngModel'], namedFn)`.

Debounce this named function. You can use debounce function in [UnderscoreJS](http://underscorejs.org/#debounce). This will ensure that the named function gets called after watched changes stop arriving.

```
scope.$watch(attr['ngModel'], _.debounce(namedFn, 300));
```

Answer (score 0):

it works fine, but the element does not remove, it hides only,

```
      app.directive("formValidate", function() {
return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    template: '<p>Please Fill this Field</p>',
    //scope: true,
    link: function(scope, elem, attr) {

        scope.$watch(attr['ngModel'], function(value) {

                var NameValidator = angular.element("<p class='NameError'>This field is required!</p>");
                var EmailValidator = angular.element("<p class='EmailError'>This Email is Invalid!</p>");
                var PhoneValidator = angular.element("<p class='PhoneError'>Enter Number Only</p>");

                if (attr['name'] == "name") {
                    if (((value || '').toString()).length == 0) {

                        NameValidator.insertAfter(elem);
                        return;


                    } else {
                        var nameRemove = elem[0].nextSibling;
                        nameRemove.remove();

                    }
                }


                if (attr['name'] == 'email') {

                    if (!(/^[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$/.test(value))) {
                        if (!scope.emailRemove) {
                            EmailValidator.insertAfter(elem);
                            scope.emailRemove = elem[0].nextSibling;
                        }
                    } else {
                        scope.emailRemove.remove();
                    }
                }
                if (attr['name'] == 'number') {
                    if (!(/^[(]{0,1}[0-9]{3}[)]{0,1}[-\s\.]{0,1}[0-9]{3}[-\s\.]{0,1}[0-9]{4}$/.test(value))) {
                        if (!scope.phoneRemove) {
                            PhoneValidator.insertAfter(elem);
                            scope.phoneRemove = elem[0].nextSibling;
                        }

                    } else {

                        scope.phoneRemove.remove();

                    }
                }
            })
            // var select = angular.element("<p>Name is Required</p>");
            // elem.append(select);
            // if (attr.name === "name") {  
            //     elem.bind('blur', function() {
            //         scope.$apply(function() {
            //             elem.replaceWith(select);
            //         })
            //     })
            // }
    }
}
});
```